# CDbCommand::fetchColumn() failed: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, yii

I want to be able to get some output from mysql stored procedure within OUT params but for case when stored procedure also returns result set via select statement like one below.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `RD`.`sp`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `sp`(in b int, out a int)
BEGIN
select 664656 into a;

select 5;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Runing in console below mentioned command one by one

```
call sp(5,@a)
select @a
```

we will get result
    5 =>  5
    @a => 664656

However when I try to run the same code from php getting error below

```
[error] [system.db.CDbCommand] CDbCommand::fetchColumn() failed: 
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active.  
Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll().  
Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql,
 you may enable query buffering by setting the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute.. The SQL statement executed was: select @a as result;.
```

Below please find my php code.

```
$connection = Yii::app ()->db;
    $b=7;
    $command = $connection->createCommand ( "CALL sp(:b,@a)" );
    $command->bindParam ( ":b", $b, PDO::PARAM_INT );
    $command->execute();

    $command->getPdoStatement()->fetchAll();

    $command->getPdoStatement()->closeCursor();

    $valueOut = $connection->createCommand ( "select @a as result;" )->queryScalar ();


    echo $valueOut;
```

Any Ideas how to fix???

PHP Version 5.3.1

Yii version 1.1.9

Mysql Version 5.1.41-3ubuntu12.10

Comment: can anyone help with problem please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end I found issues and it was with php version.
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=39858
I updated version till PHP Version 5.3.2 and it works fine now.
please take in consideration that it doesn't work under windows for the same version and only works under linux.(At least for me).

Comment: I have PHP 5.4.7 and I have issues on a simple ->query

Comment: are you on windows or linux?