# how to get mysql stored procedure output param in yii framework

Tags: php, stored-procedures, yii

I am using Yii to deal with a mysql stored procedure. The sp takes several parameter, one of which is a output parameter.

After execute the sp, when I try to get the output parameter, I run into a error

CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active. Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll(). Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute.. The SQL statement executed was: select @error_info as result;

My mock up code is like:

```
$sql = 'CALL p_bid(:username, @param)';
$command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql);
$command->bindParam(":username", $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$command->execute();

// the following line raise the error
$errorInfo = Yii::app()->db->createCommand("select @error_info as result;")->queryScalar();
```

How can I walk around the question? Thanks.

Comment: The mock up code has a typing error, param should be error_info'

Comment: Just click on "edit" to edit your post. :)

Comment: Might be worth checking out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017861/cdbcommandfetchcolumn-failed-sqlstatehy000-general-error-2014-cannot-ex?rq=1
According to that post its a PHP error, and was fixed by updating to PHP 5.3.2.

Comment: Thanks for your clue, I will try your suggestion and come back later.

Comment: Sorry for come back late. My PHP version is 5.3.15, it should have this fixed right?

Comment: Additional info, I am on Mac system, is the bug OS-dependented?

Comment: I have figured it out, it is my mistake not to use it correctly. I should add the following lines. $command->getPdoStatement()->fetchAll();
261         $command->getPdoStatement()->closeCursor();

Answer (score 2):

Try this, It's working for me

```
$command = $connection->createCommand("CALL r emove_places(:user_id,:placeID,:place_type,@out)"); 
$command->bindParam(":user_id",$user_id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$command->bindParam(":placeID",$placeID,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$command->bindParam(":place_type",$place_type,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$command->execute();
$valueOut = $connection->createCommand("select @out as result;")->queryScalar();
```